# How many characters can I fit in a control, WP7 Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox

I want to take a dynamic string of text, and break it up so that it will fit in one or more textboxes or textblocks. Preferably textboxes.
So let's say I get a string of text thats 132 characters long, but I can only display 40 characters in the textbox before it goes out of view. So, I want to break up the text into 4 textboxes. I want to find out programatically how many characters can be displayed.

I tried ActualWidth, but get 0.0.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to measure text on the phone. If you were only ever going to use a fixed text size you could measure all the characters in advance and calculate accordingly.

However, you may find it easier to use the same method as in http://nerdplusart.com/texttrimming-textblock-for-silverlight to override MeasureOverride and trim the text until it fits.

Comment: Well, since the goal is to get the entire text VISIBLE but on separate lines, this wouldn't fix it. 

As to this, and other questions I've posted, I cannot ACCEPT and answer if it doesn't really resolve my issue. Usually, I have to find some other way of modifying the code or user interface that is less than favorable to get the job done.

In this instance, I am left with putting the text in one textblock with wrapping, lumping all the lines in one box instead of separating it into separate controls.

I suppose it would help if I could give an example, but I'm not allowed to.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting this as a total answer, rather a way of determining how many characters you could fit in a line of text.